# TimeStamp issue

Tags: esb, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm having trouble with this code snippet:

```
DECLARE FormattedTimeStamp TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE pattern CHARACTER 'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss';
SET FormattedTimeStamp = CAST(EnvRef.ConsumerTrxnsInq.paymentList[i].TransactionDate as DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-MM-dd');
SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns:ConsumerTrxnsInqRs.Body.ConsumerTransaction[i].Timestamp = CAST(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CAST(FormattedTimeStamp AS CHAR) before '.'),' ','T') AS TIMESTAMP FORMAT pattern);
```

When I run it, it produces this error:

```
Error while casting. subParse failed. TIMESTAMPT'2014-12-02T15:39:21. yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss. TIMESTAMPT'2014-12-02T15:39:21. yyyy.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is issue with you'r pattern you defined. Please correct it as following..
It should work..

```
  DECLARE pattern CHARACTER 'yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with T-SQL, then
First of all replace

```
DECLARE FormattedTimeStamp TIMESTAMP
```

with

```
DECLARE @FormattedTimeStamp TIMESTAMP
```